# ListView items are empty in higher API

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

I'm new to Android.

My problem is that my ListView items Views aren't appearing on API higher than 19.

While I was creating project I set target API to KitKat (API 19) but now when I look at build.app the `targetSdkVersion` is 23 and `minSdkVersion` is 14.

Then I upgraded my phone to Marshmellow and now while I want to debug project on the phone, it works perfectly fine but my ListView items are empty and there should be TextViews... In other hand everything works fine, even ListView items on emulated phone with KitKat.

I used ArrayAdapter and Cursor to get data from SQLite db.

Is there any other way expect create this project from start to make it work properly on higher APIs?

**build.app**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.asd.sqlite1"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'

}
```

ListView class

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;

 public class RefuelListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     ListView RefuelListView;
     SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
     DBHelper dbHelper;
     Cursor cursor;
     RefuelListAdapter refuelListAdapter;

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.refuel_list);

        android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        if (getSupportActionBar() != null){
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        }

        RefuelListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.refuel_tab_list_view);


        refuelListAdapter = new RefuelListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.refuel_list_item);
         RefuelListView.setAdapter(refuelListAdapter);

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
        sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();


        cursor = dbHelper.getAllInformations(sqLiteDatabase);


        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){ 
            do{
                int fuel_id;
                float fuel_amount, fuel_price, cash_spend, km_counter;
                String fuel_date;

                // (0.id, 1.fuel_amount, 2.fuel_price, 3.cash_spend, 4.km_counter, 5.fuel_date)

                fuel_id = cursor.getInt(0);
                fuel_amount = cursor.getFloat(1);
                fuel_price = cursor.getFloat(2);
                cash_spend = cursor.getFloat(3);
                km_counter = cursor.getFloat(4);
                fuel_date = cursor.getString(5);


                RefuelListDataProvider refuelListDataProvider = new RefuelListDataProvider(fuel_id, fuel_amount,fuel_price,cash_spend,km_counter,fuel_date);
                refuelListAdapter.add(refuelListDataProvider);


            }while (cursor.moveToNext()); 
        }
    }
 }
```

Adapter Class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RefuelListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    List list = new ArrayList();
    public RefuelListAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    static class LayoutHandler{

        TextView KM_COUNTER, FUEL_AMOUNT, FUEL_PRICE, CASH_SPEND, FUEL_DATE;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Object object) {
        super.add(object);
        list.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        LayoutHandler layoutHandler;
        if (row == null){
            //No idea what this is doing...
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.refuel_list_item,parent,false);
            layoutHandler = new LayoutHandler();
            layoutHandler.KM_COUNTER = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.lv_refuel_km_counter_text);
            layoutHandler.FUEL_AMOUNT = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.lv_refuel_fuel_amount_text);
            layoutHandler.FUEL_PRICE = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.lv_refuel_fuel_price_text);
            layoutHandler.CASH_SPEND = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.lv_refuel_cost_text);
            layoutHandler.FUEL_DATE = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.lv_refuel_data_text);

            row.setTag(layoutHandler);
        }
        else { layoutHandler = (LayoutHandler)row.getTag(); }

        RefuelListDataProvider refuelListDataProvider = (RefuelListDataProvider)this.getItem(position);

        layoutHandler.KM_COUNTER.setText(String.valueOf(refuelListDataProvider.getKm_counter()));
        layoutHandler.FUEL_AMOUNT.setText(String.valueOf(refuelListDataProvider.getFuel_amount()));
        layoutHandler.FUEL_PRICE.setText(String.valueOf(refuelListDataProvider.getFuel_price()));
        layoutHandler.CASH_SPEND.setText(String.valueOf(refuelListDataProvider.getCash_spend()));
        layoutHandler.FUEL_DATE.setText(refuelListDataProvider.getFuel_date());

        return row;
    }
}
```

I also use Data Provider class.

```
public class RefuelListDataProvider {

    private int fuel_id;
    private float fuel_amount, fuel_price, cash_spend, km_counter;
    private String fuel_date;

    public RefuelListDataProvider(Integer fuel_id, Float fuel_amount, Float fuel_price, Float cash_spend, Float km_counter, String fuel_date){

        this.fuel_id = fuel_id;
        this.fuel_amount = fuel_amount;
        this.fuel_price = fuel_price;
        this.cash_spend = cash_spend;
        this.km_counter = km_counter;
        this.fuel_date = fuel_date;
    }

    public int getFuel_id() {
        return fuel_id;
    }

    public void setFuel_id(int fuel_id) {
        this.fuel_id = fuel_id;
    }

    public float getCash_spend() {
        return cash_spend;
    }

    public void setCash_spend(float cash_spend) {
        this.cash_spend = cash_spend;
    }

    public float getFuel_amount() {
        return fuel_amount;
    }

    public void setFuel_amount(float fuel_amount) {
        this.fuel_amount = fuel_amount;
    }

    public String getFuel_date() {
        return fuel_date;
    }

    public void setFuel_date(String fuel_date) {
        this.fuel_date = fuel_date;
    }

    public float getFuel_price() {
        return fuel_price;
    }

    public void setFuel_price(float fuel_price) {
        this.fuel_price = fuel_price;
    }

    public float getKm_counter() {
        return (km_counter);
    }

    public void setKm_counter(float km_counter) {
        this.km_counter = km_counter;
    }
}
```

Comment: where and when do you fill DB?

Comment: In other activity, when user calls it. It works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. To solve this problem I changed one lane in my RefuelListActivity:

```
refuelListAdapter = new RefuelListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.refuel_list_item);
```

to

```
refuelListAdapter = new RefuelListAdapter(this,R.layout.refuel_list_item);
```

And it is working fine now. 
Thanks for help I guess.